# How to create custom rules for html in SonarQube?

Tags: html, sonarqube, rules

I need to add some custom rule for html into sonarqube 6.4 Thanks to suggest me some custom html plugin if already available or you can suggest me how can i create custom plugin for html.

Comment: `some custom rule` ← add more information what this rule should do, please.

Comment: have you able to write custom rules for html. if you have any template please let me know.  I'm also looking for custom rules for xml